# Changing default admin column sorting to an ACF Date Picker field

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

**EDIT:** I can't delete my question because of the open bounty, but it looks like the problem is caused by the "Post Types Order" plugin I have installed. I have it set to not order `news` post types, but for some reason it's still adding its sorting to the main query. It's my mistake, you should always disable plugins when debugging issues.

I'm trying to set the default sorting on a column for my custom post type `news`. The column sorts fine when the heading is clicked on, but when you first visit the post listing it will only sort by the default sorting (published date). Here's my `pre_get_posts` action:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( !is_admin() || $pagenow !== 'edit.php' )
        return;

    $post_type = $query->get( 'post_type' );
    $order_by = $query->get( 'orderby' );

    if ( $post_type == 'news' ) {
        if ( empty( $order_by ) )
            $order_by = 'news-date';

        switch ( $order_by ) {
            case 'news-date':
                $query->set( 'meta_key', 'date' );
                $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
                break;
        }
    }
} );
```

After sorting manually by clicking the heading the URL becomes `edit.php?post_type=news&orderby=news-date&order=asc` so I'm sure all my parameters match up.

I tried adding a `var_dump( $query );` in the switch statement after setting the query and the query includes the updated `meta_key` and `orderby` values, so I'm assuming the query is being modified correctly, but still it's doing the default sorting.

I thought maybe the `date` meta key was already used for some reason (maybe by a plugin) so I checked the `wp_postmeta` table in the database but the only meta keys named `date` were the values set with the ACF Date Picker, so everything is fine there.

Hopefully it's just something stupid I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it looks like the problem is caused by the "Post Types Order" plugin I
>   have installed

Yes, I believe so because your code actually worked for me, but after I installed and activated the [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/), your code no longer worked as expected.

> I have it set to not order `news` post types, but for some reason it's
>   still adding its sorting to the main query.

I don't know how you set it, but try one of these:

1. Set `ignore_custom_sort` (it's a custom `WP_Query` parameter) to `true` like so:

   ```php
   switch ( $order_by ) {
       case 'news-date':
           $query->set( 'meta_key', 'date' );
           $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
           $query->set( 'ignore_custom_sort', true );
           break;
   }
   ```
2. Or you can also use the [`pto/posts_orderby/ignore`](https://www.nsp-code.com/ignore-sort-apply-for-certain-query-on-post-types-order/) hook to disable the plugin's sorting:

   ```php
   add_filter( 'pto/posts_orderby/ignore', function( $ignore, $order_by, $query ){
       if ( 'lesson' === $query->get( 'post_type' ) ) {
           $ignore = true;
       }
       return $ignore;
   }, 10, 3 );
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. I "fixed" my problem by just installing a different plugin (Simple Custom Post Order) but your answer is really good so I'll mark it as the answer and give you the bounty :)

Comment: I actually had a thought of suggesting you to just switch to another plugin, but anyway, thanks a lot. :)